# Table is not shown of full sizae in MODAL of POPUP WINDOW

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to show the table inside the MODAL of pop up of full length.But it is coming in the center with just fixed length.I have used the css but dont know what is wrong.I need to show the table of 100% length inside the MODAl.please someone help me to structure the table.I have used bootstrap table and getting such error.

```
[![<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 50%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 25px; margin-bottom: 30px; text-transform: none;">    
<form class="form-inline" action="">    
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="test" class="col-sm-3 control-label">ClientId</label>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="test" placeholder="Enter A Value">

</div>
<div class="form-group">

    <button type="button" id="go"  class="btn btn-primary"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>

</div>
</form>
<!--Modal if input is empty-->
<div class="modal fade" id="#myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" >
        <!--div class="container"-->
  <h2>Basic Table</h2>

  <div class="table-responsive" id="holder-table">       
  <!--TAble COntent-->
</div>

<!--/div-->
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

<!--modal if there is some text-->
<!--Modal-->

<div class="modal fade" id="#myModal1">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h3 class="modal-title modal-title-or">
            Edit
            Relative
            </h3>

      </div>
      <form id="relativeFormEdit" class="form-horizontal">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!--form body-->
        <div class="form-group ">
      <div class="row">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Name:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input name="name" title="Name" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
       <div class="row">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Age:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input name="age" title="age" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>

      <div class="row">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-4">Cid:</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input name="cid" title="cid" class="form-control">
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <div class="col-md-10">    
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn pull-right" id="search" >
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>Search
    </button>
                    </div>

<div id="holder-table1">
    <!--table content-->
    </div>
</div>
</div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
</form>
<div class="table-responsive">
<table id="tableModel" style="display:none" class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed" >
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Cid</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>john@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Mary</td>
        <td>11</td>
        <td>mary@example.com</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>July</td>
        <td>12</td>
        <td>july@example.com</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
$('#go').click(function() {

    var test1 = $('#test').val();
  if (test1 === "") {
    $("#tableModel").css({display: "block"});
     $('#holder-table1').append($("#tableModel"));
    $('#\\#myModal1').modal('show');
    $('#holder-table1').hide();
  }
  else{
     $("#tableModel").css({display: "block"});
     $('#holder-table').append($("#tableModel"));
    $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
  }
$('#search').click(function() {
   $("#tableModel").css({display: "block"});
        $("#holder-table1").show();
    });
});
});
</script>
<!-- /.modal -->
<!--End Modal-->
</body>
</html>][1]][1]
```

Comment: you use `width: 50%;` in `table class` use `100%`

Comment: its still not working

Comment: can you post the code in a jsfiddle so we can test it?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ashwinkarki/523mgbbh/ test it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<style type="text/css">
    .table {
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    float: none;
}
</style>
```

and use `inline-table` instead of `block` in css

```
<table id="tableModel" style="display:inline-table"  class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed" > 

if (test1 === "") {
    $("#tableModel").css({display: "inline-table"});
     $('#holder-table1').append($("#tableModel"));
    $('#\\#myModal1').modal('show');
    $('#holder-table1').hide();
  }
  else{
     $("#tableModel").css({display: "inline-table"});
     $('#holder-table').append($("#tableModel"));
    $('#\\#myModal').modal('show');
  }
$('#search').click(function() {
   $("#tableModel").css({display: "inline-table"});
        $("#holder-table1").show();
    });
```

Comment: oh thnks laot thnks alotttttttttttttttttttttttttttttt

Comment: if you satisfy with my answer than accept the answer ..! Thank you.

Comment: i have alrerady ticket